# Why is Angular always loading a module with '' route?

Tags: angular

I have two different modules that I am routing to, like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module/first/first.module').then(m => m.FirstModule)
  }
  ,
  {
    path: 'second',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module/second/second.module').then(m => m.SecondModule)
  },
```

];

So, when I hit the route `/`, the first module loads (and gives a console output), which is expected. However, when I hit `/user`, both the first and second modules get loaded and both give console outputs.

So, it is kind of beating the purpose of lazy loading. What is a solution to this? I want the first module to load only when it's route is hit.

Comment: The order of the routes determine the precedence. Try to place the `path: ''` route at the end of the array.

Comment: That does the trick but is it the best way?

Comment: Yes it is the [official way](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order).